# Why do we call a limit that evaluates to $\displaystyle\pm\infty$ a particular instance of "The Limit Does Not Exist"

Tags: limits, first-order-logic

The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit is stated as:

> $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0\  \exists\delta \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [ 0\lt \lvert x -a \rvert \lt \delta \rightarrow\lvert f(x) - L \rvert \lt \epsilon \big ] \quad \dagger$

More generally, one would state:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \text{ exists} \iff \exists L \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. }  \forall \epsilon \gt 0\  \exists\delta \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [ 0\lt \lvert x -a \rvert \lt \delta \rightarrow\lvert f(x) - L \rvert \lt \epsilon \big ] $$

---

The corresponding negation of $\dagger$ is:

> $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)\neq L \iff \exists\epsilon \gt 0\  \text{ s.t. }  \forall\delta \gt 0 \ \exists x \in \mathbb R  \text{ s.t. }\big [ 0\lt \lvert x -a \rvert \lt \delta \land \lvert f(x) - L \rvert \geq \epsilon \big ] $

More generally, one would state:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \text{ does not exist} \iff \forall L \in \mathbb R\   \exists\epsilon \gt 0\  \text{ s.t. }  \forall\delta \gt 0 \ \exists x \in \mathbb R  \text{ s.t. } \big [ 0\lt \lvert x -a \rvert \lt \delta \land \lvert f(x) - L \rvert \geq \epsilon \big ] \quad \dagger \dagger$$

---

**Given the above definitions**, consider what one means for a limit evaluating to $\displaystyle \pm \infty$:

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = +\infty \iff \forall M \gt 0 \ \exists \delta \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [0 \lt \lvert x-a \rvert \lt \delta \rightarrow f(x) \gt M \big ]$

or

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = -\infty \iff \forall N \lt 0 \ \exists \delta \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [0 \lt \lvert x-a \rvert \lt \delta \rightarrow f(x) \lt N \big ]$

Within the analysis community, when one claims "$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \displaystyle  +\infty$" (or $- \infty$), I have seen that it is acceptable to claim "**The limit does not exist**".

Based on the negated expression described in $\dagger \dagger$, I am having difficulties seeing why this is justified.

Could someone explain what is meant by "the limit does not exist" in the context of infinities? It appears to me that the first order logics do not *match*.

Comment: Does not exist in $ \Bbb R $ but it exists in $ \overbar{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah well, sure. Even if I adjusted for that, my question would still remain, yes?

Comment: When analyst says "the limit does not exist", i think you can safely assume they mean in the sense of the single dagger and the double dagger. It is a little annoying at first.

Comment: Like for sequences. if the limit  is infinite, the sequence is divergent and if the limit is real, it is convergent.

Comment: You should see that the definition of $\pm\infty $ imply the negation of limit definition. In these cases there won't exist an $L$ to match the definition of limit. It should also be observed that negation of limit definition  does not imply that limit is $\pm\infty $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinity is not a number, so the real number $L$ in the definition of limit cannot “take value $\infty$.” So to verify $\dagger\dagger$, remember that $L$ is a real number.

Assume that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$; that is, as you note, that
$$\forall M\gt 0\exists \delta\gt0 (0\lt|x-a|\lt\delta\implies f(x)\gt M.$$
I claim that this function satisfies the definition of “the limit does not exist”; that is, that it satisfies what you write as $\dagger\dagger$.

(Intuitively: since $f(x)$ is getting “larger and larger, as large as we care to specify”, it can’t possibly be approaching any particular number $L$: it will be much larger than $L$ once we are close enough to $a$... now to formalize it.)

Indeed, let $L$ be any real number. If $L\leq 0$, then let $\delta\gt0$ be such that $0\lt |x-a|\lt\delta$ implies $f(x)\gt 1$. Now let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. For all $\delta_1\gt 0$, if $0<|x-a|\lt\min(\delta,\delta_1)$ (and such numbers certainly exist), then $f(x)>1$, and therefore, $|f(x)-L|=f(x)-L\geq f(x)\gt 1\gt\epsilon$.

If $L\gt 0$, let $\delta\gt0$ be such that if $0\lt|x-a|\lt\delta$ then $f(x)>L+1$. Again, let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$; for any $\delta_1\gt 0$, if $0\lt|x-a|\lt\min(\delta,\delta_1)$ (and such numbers certainly exist), then
$$|f(x)-L|= f(x)-L \gt 1\gt \epsilon.$$

Thus, for all values of $L$, there exists $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that for all $\delta_1\gt 0$ there is an $x$ such that $0\lt|x-a|\lt\delta_1$, but $|f(x)-L|\gt\epsilon$. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist.

A similar argument holds if $\lim_{x\to\infty}=-\infty$, or just apply the above argument to $g(x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: (Feel free to ignore this: just documenting my understanding of your proof): In your line, "If $L\leq 0$, then let $\delta\gt0$ be such that $0\lt |x-a|\lt\delta$ implies $f(x)\gt 1$", we can make this claim because it follows from the FOL statement: $\forall M \gt 0 \ \exists \delta \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [0 \lt \lvert x-a \rvert \lt \delta \rightarrow f(x) \gt M \big ]$. In particular, you are choosing the value of $1$ for $M$.

Comment: @S.Cramer: Yes; and in the second part I chose the value of $M$ to be $L+1$.

Comment: This was just what I wanted. Thank you *very* much! Cheers~

Comment: More generally then, what I am really saying is that: 

$$ \text{ if } \forall M \gt 0 \ \exists \delta \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb R \big [0 \lt \lvert x-a \rvert \lt \delta \rightarrow f(x) \gt M \big ]$$

$$ \text{ then } \forall L \in \mathbb R\   \exists\epsilon \gt 0\  \text{ s.t. }  \forall\delta \gt 0 \ \exists x \in \mathbb R  \text{ s.t. } \big [ 0\lt \lvert x -a \rvert \lt \delta \land \lvert f(x) - L \rvert \geq \epsilon \big ]$$ (where the converse is *not* necessarily true)

Comment: Well, that’s what we are all saying, which is why when the limit “equals $\infty$ or $-\infty$”, it really means “the limit does not exist, and it does not exist for a very specific reason from among all possible ways in which a limit can fail to exist.”

Answer (score 2):

One answer, of course, is the argument described in the OP—the limit "equaling" infinity satisfies the negation of the definition of the limit existing.

We could just change the definition if we wanted to; but there are lots of reasons we don't want to. Here's one representative one:

It's a theorem, easy to prove from the definition, that: *If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exist and are equal, then $\lim_{x\to a} (f(x)-g(x))=0$.*

That theorem is definitely false in the case $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=\infty$.

(The mantra I always teach to my students is: *Infinity is not a number.* We use the notation $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$ to describe a phenomenon, a specific and useful-to-record way that a limit can fail to exist. But the equals sign can fool us into thinking all sorts of false things if we reason by analogy to limits that actually exist. For all intents and purposes, we should pretend that there is a different symbol than $=$ in $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$.)

Comment: well said. If we could go back in time, we might twist some arms to establish a less misleading notation. Maybe that's why I like to write $f(x) \to +\infty\,$ as $x \to a.$

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb{R}$ denotes the set of finite reals, not the set $\Bbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$ of extended reals. If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \pm \infty$ under the standard definition that you give, then $f(x)$ has no finite limit as $x \to \infty$, which makes the right-hand side of your definition $\dagger\dagger$ false. I think you are forgetting that the $L$ in $\dagger\dagger$ ranges over $\Bbb{R}$, i.e., over finite reals.